# Appropriate .Net data type for decimal(20,0)

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssis, types

I've got some sql returning a decimal(20,0) data type.  In SSIS I have a package with a foreach loop.  In my variable mappings, what type of variable would I map it to?  I've tried Int32, Int64, double, and still get the error "The type of the value being assigned to variable "User::iID" differs from the current variable type..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SSIS variable designer did not, in my case, show the Decimal or Numeric data types to select to place my decimal(18,2) value into.

I changed my variable to Object, and was able to read the Decimal(18,2) value from the result set of one stored proc, and pass it as a parameter with type Money to a second SP.

So I would use "Object" if you cannot find a type in the variable list that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Decimal yet?

Comment: There is no option for decimal or float in the ssis designer

Answer (score 1):

SSIS does have Decimal and Numeric types.  You can use either of these and it'll go through (except maybe on a Union All, where you should make sure they're the same precision and scale).

See more about data types [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036.aspx).

Comment: Where? In the variables window, I can pick Boolean, DBNull,Double, Int16, Int32, Int64, Object, SByte, String, UInt32, UInt64  but no decimal or numeric

Answer (score 0):

.NET decimal has methods **decimal.ToInt64()**, **decimal.ToInt32()** etc.

Answer (score 0):

A float or a decimal would be my recommendation.

Comment: There is no option for decimal or float in the ssis designer

Answer (score 0):

A SQL decimal(20,0) has a precision of 20 which equates to 13 bytes of storage. The .Net decimal is 16 bytes and should work.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to convert the SQL data type to an Int64 prior to putting it into a Int64 package variable.

How are you getting it, as an output parameter?

In a dataflow, you would obviously read it into a decimal/numeric and then convert to Int64 in a Data Conversion component.

If you're trying to directly map an output parameter from an Execute SQL Command task, you'll probably have to use a temporary object package variable and then convert it in a script task into the real Int64 package variable.